# How to cause dynamically created controls not to disappear when clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I have written a code-behind (in c#) for a Button to create a control (ImageButton) when I press it and defined a Click event handler for this control. How can I force this control not to disappear and to fire its Click event handler when I click it? I'd like the control to be created as a result of clicking the Button, so it cannot be created in the OnInit() method as it is recommended in other answers.

**Code**

```
protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Button btn = (Button)sender; 
    Control box = btn.Parent; 
    ImageButton lamp = new ImageButton(); 
    lamp.ID = "MyLamp"; lamp.ImageUrl = "grey_lamp.jpg"; 
    lamp.Style["Position"] = "absolute"; 
    lamp.Style["Top"] = "40px"; 
    lamp.Style["Left"] = "100px"; 
    lamp.Style["Height"] = "20px"; 
    lamp.Click += Image3_Click; 
    box.Controls.Add(lamp); 
    CreateNewTable(); 
    base.OnInit(e); 
}
```

Comment: Can you not just make it Visible when you click the button? Visible = false means it won't be rendered at all on the client.

Comment: No, I can't. The number of ImageButtons to be created in such a way is not known in advance.

Comment: It might be helpful to see some of your code to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Control box = btn.Parent;
        ImageButton lamp = new ImageButton();
        lamp.ID = "MyLamp";
        lamp.ImageUrl = "grey_lamp.jpg";
        lamp.Style["Position"] = "absolute";
        lamp.Style["Top"] = "40px";
        lamp.Style["Left"] = "100px";
        lamp.Style["Height"] = "20px";
        lamp.Click += Image3_Click;
        box.Controls.Add(lamp);
        CreateNewTable();
        base.OnInit(e);  
    }`

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of adding a control through code

```
// the method; your button click method
private void ButtonClick() { 
   // create a new control
   // my example would be a button
   Button newButton = new Button();
   // the button's content
   newButton.Content = "Im a new button";
   // the click event listener
   newButton.Click += (_, __) => { // params: object sender, Clickeventargs
      // here should be the instructions of the button to perform when clicked
      Debug.Writeline("The new button has been clicked");
      // do some amazing stuffs
   }

   // add the button to the parent control; a grid or stachpanel, etc.
   someParentControl.Children.Add(newButton);
}
```

Comment: I have forgotten to mention that this is asp.net. There is no Children option for a control. And Controls.Add does not help.